# A-Frame - VR Mode mouse control / move in browser

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm really new with A-Frame / Web VR. I'd like to ask you when I am on my mobile  in VR mode how can I prevent the controll / camera move? For example when I switch to VR mode I want to use my usb mouse for moving just like in "normal mode" and not the device's sensor. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible. Another potential issue with this approach is that it will likely cause simulator sickness:

> The most important guideline in designing for virtual reality is to always maintain head tracking. Never stop tracking the user’s head position inside of the application. Even a short pause in head tracking will cause some users to feel ill.

https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/cardboard/designing-for-google-cardboard/physiological-considerations.html

That said, if you're purpose for this functionality is for spectating on a 2d screen, A-Frame 0.8.0 allows you to add a spectator camera:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/camera.html#properties

There are no tutorials for this yet, but you could try adding asking another question here or on a-frame slack on how to get it up and running.